# Python Polars Parse Date from Epoch

Tags: python, python-polars

How does one convert a column of i64 epoch strings into dates in polars?

I've got a column of i64 representing seconds since epoch and I'd like to parse them into polars native datetimes.

Comment: Assuming it is `pandas` compliant, you would use `df['yourcolumn'] = pd.to_datetime(df['yourcolumn'])`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Polars' `Datetime` is represented as unix epoch in either, nanoseconds, microseconds or milliseconds. So with that knowledge we can convert the seconds to milliseconds and cast to `Datetime`.

Finally we ensure polars uses the proper unit.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "epoch_seconds": [1648457740, 1648457740 + 10]
})

MILLISECONDS_IN_SECOND = 1000;

df.select(
    (pl.col("epoch_seconds") * MILLISECONDS_IN_SECOND).cast(pl.Datetime).dt.with_time_unit("ms").alias("datetime")
)
```

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌─────────────────────┐
│ datetime            │
│ ---                 │
│ datetime[ms]        │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 2022-03-28 08:55:40 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-03-28 08:55:50 │
└─────────────────────┘
```

Comment: is it possible to get 5 minutes floor of datetime or with from epoch using polars without developing python udf?

Answer (score 1):

This is for node.js, but I felt like this is still a good place to post this since I was looking here for help when doing it in node, and because the apis are similar.

```js
const startTime = new Date('2022')
const endTime = new Date('2023')

df = pl.DataFrame().withColumns(
    pl
        .arange(startTime, endTime, 15 * 60 * 1000)
        .cast(pl.DataType.Datetime("ms"))
        .alias("datetime")
)
```

Somehow I had to use `pl.DataType.Datetime` instead of `pl.Datetime`, which is a bit different from what can be seen in tests: [https://github.com/pola-rs/nodejs-polars/blob/main/**tests**/setup.ts](https://github.com/pola-rs/nodejs-polars/blob/main/__tests__/setup.ts) ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ but it works

---

edit: Having to use `pl.DataType.Datetime` is a side-effect of a specific project configuration. See https://github.com/pola-rs/nodejs-polars/issues/55 for more details

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a slight variation of the above. If df_1 is a dataframe of three columns (datetime_open, datetime_close, close), and all three columns were strings...I can cast all three to a new var (df_2) using one step in Polars as follows:

`df_2 = (df_1.with_columns([pl.from_epoch(column="datetime_open", time_unit="ms"), pl.from_epoch(column="datetime_close", time_unit="ms"), pl.col("close").cast(pl.Float32, strict=True)]))`

Key bits are:

- I used `pl.with_columns` to modify each column in one command
- I used `pl.from_epoch` to cast the string date to a Unix/datetime64[ns] date
- I used `pl.cast` to cast other types (eg. pl.Float32, pl.UInt64, pl.Utf8)
- You can convert/cast any column in this way

Hope this helps.